# Replace javascript modifica apenas o último termo

Tags: javascript

Estou usando o código javascript para coloca em negrito os termos pesquisados, mas se o termo se repetir ele altera apenas o último e também eu gostaria que não fosse case sensitive:

por exemplo, na string: `Brilha o Sol, como brilha o Sol do meio dia`
fica: `Brilha o Sol, como **brilha** o **Sol** do meio dia.

```
$q = 'Sol brilha'
var searchTerm = $q.split(" ");
 
$(".resultado").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html().toString();
    for(var i = 0; i < searchTerm.length; i++) {
        var pattern = "([^\w]*)(" + searchTerm[i] + ")([^\w]*)";
        var rg = new RegExp(pattern);
        var match = rg.exec(html);
        if(match) {
            html = html.replace(rg,match[1] + "<b>"+ match[2] +"</b>" + match[3]);
            $(this).html(html);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos passo a passo.

**Buscando palavras com RegExp**

Uma das formas de pesquisar uma palavra, é utilizar o metacaractere `\b`, ou [Word Boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), disponível no Regex. Com ele, existem três posições diferentes que se qualificam como limites de palavras:

- Antes do primeiro caractere do texto, se o primeiro caractere for um caractere de palavra.

```
"Brilha o Sol, como brilha o Sol do meio dia brilhantemente".match(/\Bbrilha/gi)
// Output: ["Brilha", "brilha", "brilha"]
```

- Após o último caractere do texto, se o último caractere for um caractere de palavra.

```
"Brilha o Sol, como brilha o Sol do meio dia brilhantemente".match(/Brilha\b/gi)
// Output: ["Brilha", "brilha"]
```

- Entre dois caracteres no texto, onde um é um caractere de palavra e o outro não é um caractere de palavra.

```
"Brilha o Sol, como brilha o Sol do meio dia brilhantemente".match(/\bBrilha\b/gi)
// Output: ["Brilha", "brilha"]
```

Simplificando: `\b` permite que você busque palavras inteiras.

**Buscando termos com case-insensitive**

Quando instanciamos a classe/função `RegExp` no *JavaScript*, nós podemos passar *flags* que podem nos auxiliar. Uma dessas é `i`, que significa ignorar maiúsc./minúsc. A outra, `g`, que corresponde à busca global, ou seja, ela acha todas as correspondências em vez de parar após achar a primeira.

**Refatoração**

Em vez de utilizar `([^\w]*)` para encontrar os termos antes e depois da palavra que queremos encontrar, passei a utilizar o símbolo de *pipe* `|`. Quando o utilizamos (`\b(brilha|sol)\b`), estamos informando que queremos buscar tanto o termo *brilha* quanto *sol*. Isso evita um *loop* desnecessário e melhora a performance em textos longos.

Na função [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), optei por utilizar *substrings*, como segundo parâmetro, para adicionar a palavra dentro da *tag bold*. Podemos usar *substring* da seguinte forma: `$n` ou `$nn` onde `n` ou `nn` são valores numéricos inteiros que insere a enésima *substring* entre parêntesis (chamados de grupos), dado o primeiro argumento foi um objeto *RegExp*.

**Código de exemplo:**

```js
$q = 'sol brilha'
var searchTerm = $q.split(" ");
 
$(".resultado").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html().toString();
    var pattern = "\\b(" + searchTerm.join('|') + ")\\b";
    var rg = new RegExp(pattern, 'ig');
    var match = rg.exec(html);

    html = html.replace(rg, "<b>$1</b>");
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="resultado">Brilha o Sol, como brilha o Sol do meio dia</div>
```

Comment: Tem alguma necessidade para o `if (match) {`? Penso que, se não houver, o `replace` simplesmente não irá fazer nada, certo? Porque do jeito como está, teoricamente duas "varreduras" estão sendo feitas.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Verdade! Agradeço pelo toque.